# Create Survey app, using api for certain questions

Tags: python, api, sharepoint, spotify, powerapps

I need to create a survey, but one of my questions needs to use the spotify API. How can I do this? *NOT ASKING FOR CODE* I just want to know what platform I should be looking at

example:  "out of the top 20 artists, pick 3 you like"

I need to integrate the api in order to display the 20 artists in real time whenever someone uses the app to take the survey.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @Ivonet I'm not asking for code, I just want to know what platform I should be looking at. Any help is appreciated. I tried google forms, but  what I'm trying to do isn't supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the PowerApps platform.  You use the spotify API by creating a custom API in PowerApps.  [Here is an example of a custom API used in PowerApps.](https://baizini-it.com/blog/index.php/2017/12/18/powerapps-cryptocurrency-exchange-rate-api-custom-connector/)